# Multiple simultaneous instances of apt-get

Tags: apt, concurrency

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

What does these exceptions mean? I am getting these errors when I am trying to install simultaneously? Is there any means to avoid them??

Answer (score 5):

You can only install one program at a time.  This is because the package manager checks dependencies. Make sure you have sudo permissions also. However you can specify multiple packages on one install line.
`sudo apt-get install -y emacs git`
This would install both emacs and git. One after another not at the same time.

Maybe useful to link: https://superuser.com/questions/169759/installing-two-things-at-the-same-time-on-linux